# Equivalent of fgetc with Unix file descriptors

Tags: c, unix, io, stream, file-descriptor

The `fgetc(3)` function takes a `FILE *` as its input stream. Must I reimplement character-at-a-time input with `read(2)`, or is there a `<unistd.h>`-style equivalent taking an integer file descriptor instead?

Comment: `integer file descriptor` ?

Comment: `ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);` from the manpage.

Comment: So you want to `open` file using an `int variable` ?

Comment: Yes, that would be the standard way of opening a file with `open(2)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't such a thing, and please **never** do *read(fd, &ch, sizeof(char))* (explanations below).

The function *read(2)* is usually implemented as a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) to the operating system [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)). Although the internal (and funky) details of such a thing shall not be discused here, the overall idea is that system calls are (usually) *not* something cheap.

It would be inefficient for both the userspace application and the kernel to do a system call just to get a single character from a file descriptor.

For instance, *fgetc(3)* usually ends up doing some buffering inside the structure of the *FILE* object. This means that the internal *read(2)* from *fgetc(3)* wouldn't just read a single character, but rather it'll try to get more for the sake of efficiency.

Anyway, it's not usually a good idea to mess up with such low-level stuff. You can get all the benefits of buffering (and of *FILE*s overall) by using [fdopen(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fdopen.html) to create a *FILE* object from a file descriptor, as your question appears to imply that you have at hand just a raw file descriptor at the moment.

Comment: Actually the shell builtin `read` command **has to** repeatedly call `read` with a length of 1 byte/character, because it has to leave everything past the newline unread for the next command to read. So despite it being horribly inefficient, there are times you have no choice.

Comment: This is not true. A shell may use some kind of buffer to store "wrongly prefetched" command strings for future use. I've actually done this one or another time, and this still preserves efficiency, so there's still no need for `read(fd, &ch, sizeof(char))`.

Comment: "**never**": How about when I need to read one byte from a unix pipe (the inspiration of this question)? Maybe avoid "never" in answers – qualify it with the context in which it is an unnacceptable choice.

Comment: @KemyLand: No, the shell cannot do that. If a shell reads one character and then returns, so that whatever process invokes it continues, the parent process must be able to read starting from the next character, regardless of what kind of thing the input is. (Regular files can be seek()ed backwards, but you can't do that with sockets, pipes and terminals.)

Comment: @Felix Tyson: Well... you can always unbuffer the *FILE* with *setvbuf(3)*, and so, again, *read(2)* provides no benefits over *fgetc(3)*. Anyway you can always read a single byte from a pipe, be it buffered or not, with any of those two routines. BTW, maybe I shouldn't use **never** in the future, that word seems to cause undesirable conflicts, although I still think there's no need for using *read(2)* directly.

Comment: @KemyLand: As rici remarked, it won't necessarily be the shell that reads next. If you have a highly optimizing shell interpreter, it might be able to determine that it will be the next to perform a read, but in general it will be some other external command that does the next read. Thus you really are stuck with single-byte reads. Just use `strace` and see what any real-world shell does.

Comment: @R..: @rici: Well, I apologize. A simple `strace` confirmed that the shell does read a single byte at a time in unbuffered mode, which I think all of us here agree it's pretty inefficient (now I know why the shell can be so slow). (@R..: Somehow I did the `strace` before your edit :))

Comment: @kemyland: it is slow. But it cannot be inefficient unless there is a better way to do it, and sometimes there just isn't. ("Efficient" isn't a fancy way of saying "fast". It means " using as few resources *as possible* to solve the problem.")

Comment: @rici: Here's an interesting side-effect of character-at-a-time I/O in the shell — at a command line, type a single line of input containing: `cat > objection; echo this is incorrect`, but type control-D after the semicolon (and another after the newline). Because the shell does CaaT input, it runs the `cat` before the newline is typed, so the file `objection` contains `echo this is incorrect` as file content, instead of it being the rest of the command line. It's also why you needed a second control-D (or an interrupt).  I'm tempted to claim 'bug', but no-one would do that in normal practice.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I had some trouble reproducing that. Eventually, I worked out that you need to `set -o vi`, because in the default emacs binding C-d is bound to delete-char, which deletes the character under the cursor and is a no-op if the cursor is at the end of the line. In vi mode, C-d is bound to "vi-eof-maybe", which makes the character act like a newline. In both modes, the terminal's EOF character is interpreted as an EOF if it is the first character typed in a line, regardless of what the character is bound to. readline turns ICANON off, so it gets to interpret Ctl-D....

Comment: @rici.   Hmmm...I suppose there is the other half of the world that prefers emacs.  Yes, I use `set -o vi`, but it didn't occur to me that emacs mode would bind the EOF terminal signal to something other than EOF.  And the key point is the behaviour of EOF/Control-D part-way through the line.  I'm not sure of the implications of 'vi-eof-maybe' beyond it confuses the heck out of old school programmers (e.g. me).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Some of the above is documented in the bash manual here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Commands-For-Text but I can't find precise documentation for some of the readline functions used in vi mode, including the one I mentioned above. The code is quite simple, though: `int rl_vi_eof_maybe (count, c)     int count, c;  { return (rl_newline (1, '\n')); }`

Comment: @rici: Since it is only an issue in interactive mode, and no-one in their right mind would do it, it probably passes as 'WAD — working as designed' (though maybe the design is a little more intricate, convoluted and non-obvious than I'd like).  Well researched.  It isn't a major practical problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: For as long as I can remember, `man readline` has ended with `BUGS: It's too big and too slow.` I've often that that it should also say something like, ".. and too intricate, convoluted and non-obvious".

Comment: @rici: And still using non-prototype C; ugh!  Best to close the eyes and turn aside quickly, leaving well alone.  :D  Should I put my observation into a question which you can answer, or shall we leave it here as an extensive footnote?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: As you say, it is extremely unlikely that anyone will do that (and 50% less likely that they will do it in vi mode :) )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to, you can open a file using [`open()`](ftp://ftp.tuwien.ac.at/languages/c/programming-bbrown/c_075.htm) -

```
int fh = open("abc.txt", O_RDONLY, S_IREAD);  // there are different permissions you can provide (refer to link).
```

and then you can use `fh` in `read()` calls.

Comment: Note that the Linux manual page for [`stat()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) documents that `S_IREAD` is not standard in POSIX and so `S_IREAD` should not be used in new code; use the POSIX standard `S_IRUSR` instead.  Then you could note that `open()` is a variadic function; it may be called with 2 or 3 arguments.  If the second argument includes `O_CREAT`, then it is crucial that the third argument is present and set sanely.  When, as in this example, there is no file creation, there is no need for the third argument (though, were it set appropriately, I'd not object).